# what does "to say" mean in beginning of a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I'm struggling in understanding this sentence:

"To say that I had low expectations would be to underestimate the matter dramatically."

Comment: To say: to imagine

Comment: @Willow post an answer with your comment to marking it as right answer. thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is there to add emphasis. It means, "If you thought that I had low expectations, you would be very much overestimating my hopes." Or, " I had no hope this could work and that is so much less than 'low' expectations."

Answer (score 1):

The meaning can be taken literally:  If you were **to say** the first part of the sentence, you would be doing the second part of the sentence.

But in this example, *to say* really means *to think*, as in:  "To **think** that I had low expectations would be to underestimate the matter dramatically."